# How can I generate a 404 response from an IHttpModule configured in the global web.config?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, ihttpmodule

I'm trying to generate a [404 response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) for certain requests on all sites on a server based on the [`HttpRequest.UserAgent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent.aspx).

I've configured an `IHttpModule` in the server's global `web.config` containing the code below:

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
    HttpContext context = application.Context;

    if (isBot(context.Request.UserAgent))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(
            "Application",
            "\nBotRequestChecker -- request 404d\n" + "Url: " + 
              context.Request.Url + "\nUserAgent: " + context.Request.UserAgent,
            EventLogEntryType.Information);
        context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        context.Response.StatusDescription = "Not Found";
        context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
}
```

Setting the `User-Agent` in a browser and visiting a page results in an entry in the event log, but the page is also returned, without a 404 status.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

**Update:**

The `IHttpModule` does seem to work if I add it to a single site (in the site's `web.config`), just not for all sites.

**Update 2:** 
The `IHttpModule` only works on a single site on an **IIS7** server, not on **IIS6**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've subscribed to the the BeginRequest event in your module's `IHttpModule.Init()` implementation. The events don't get auto-wired in `IHttpModule` implementations the way same they do in Global.asax.

I also missed the bit about the global web.config at first.

On a 64-bit server, you'll need to make sure you make the changes in both the 32- and 64-bit configurations (depending on the bitness that your sites are running in) in all ASP.NET versions you need to support:

```
%windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config
%windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config

%windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CONFIG\web.config
%windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CONFIG\web.config
```

If you're targeting both IIS6 and IIS7, you'll need to make sure the module is referenced in both the `<system.web>/<httpModules>` element for IIS6 and the `<system.webServer>/<modules>` element for IIS7.

Comment: That's what I tried originally, with the same non-404 result.

Comment: Edited my answer to remove that... based on this: http://forums.asp.net/p/1148761/1867921.aspx it looks like you're doing the right thing.

Can you confirm that the code is actually getting hit?

Comment: Also, are you actually testing this on an IIS 6 server or are you running in the VS dev server (Cassini) for now?

Comment: Yep -- there's event log entries being posted fro just above when the StatusCode is set.

Comment: So, regarding your addendum, are the log entries getting posted when the module is configured only at the machine level and not at the site level?

Comment: In both cases. Your question made me realize that my "working" case was on an IIS7 server.

Comment: Ah. In that case, you'll need to add module references in the `<system.webServer>/<modules>` element as well.